# Send Large number of double values from Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, service, web

I want to send a double array with large number of values from servlet to jsp page, the problem this array doesn't have certain size, the size is given as inpt from user, so some time it could contain 500.000, 720.000,etc and the max that the user can enter it as value of array size is 1,000,000.

I am using the following, and it works correctly:

(servelt)
         RequestDispatcher disp;

```
     request.setAttribute("vValues", V_Array);

     disp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");

     disp.forward(request, response);
```

(jsp)

```
         <% double[] V_Values =(double[]) request.getAttribute("vValues"); %>
```

But the problem appears when I am trying to send more than 100.000 values from servlet to jsp page, the page loads for some time, then it got crash with the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:144)
    sun.proxy.$Proxy64.getSVData(Unknown Source)
    SMC.client.SMCService.doGet(SMCService.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException invoking http://localhost:8080/SMC/services/SMPort: Read timed out
```

can you please help me, I need to solve that to be able to continue.

Thanks in advance;

Comment: I can't imagine an user who will type more than 100 items. The better solution seems to be sending a file.

Comment: the user will not type, the user will ask the program to genrate random values, so the user enter ( how many values want from my program to genrate randomly )  .. and the result will be graphical represntation

Comment: sorry, maybe my explanation wasn't so good

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to push that much amount of data from the servlet to the jsp. A page should not be filled with 100.000 or whatever huge amount of values. That's just not usable from the viewer stand point:

- a user will never want to read that amount of data
- a user will never input so many numbers by hand

If you need to receive or send an array of that size to a user, you will need to settle for a different method: store that data in a file (csv comes to mind), then send it. Likewise, for input, users will want to send the data as a file, so make the ad hoc form to upload a file.

If you need to preprocess that array to only display a few values, do the preprocessing in the servlet, not in the jsp.

Comment: the user will not type, the user will ask the program to genrate random values, so the user enter ( how many values want from my program to genrate randomly )  .. and the result will be graphical represntation

Comment: does your graphic need 100.000 values? That seems a bit excessive.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, maybe my explanation wasn't so good, I meant

The user will ask the program to genrate random values, so the user JUST enter ( how many values want from my program to genrate randomly ) .. and the result will be graphical represntation –

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be an edit on your question.

Comment: Still, the server should provide a file download with the random generated values instead of showing all of them on client. Note that you can't even do this on JavaScript.